# Can not add image to java class.can not add image to my android project.R.drawable.mylogo does not appear.

Tags: java

I m not able to add image to my android project. My code is as follows:

```
>     package com.hfad.tagamlar.dummy;
> 
> import android.media.Image; import android.widget.ImageView;
> 
> import com.hfad.tagamlar.R;
> 
> import java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.HashMap; import
> java.util.List; import java.util.Map;
> 
> 
> /**  * Helper class for providing sample content for user interfaces
> created by  * Android template wizards.  * <p/>  * TODO: Replace all
> uses of this class before publishing your app.  */
> 
> public class DummyContent3 {
> 
>     /**
>      * An array of sample (dummy) items.
>      */
>     public static final List<DummyItem> ITEMS = new ArrayList<DummyItem>();
> 
>     /**
>      * A map of sample (dummy) items, by ID.
>      */
>     public static final Map<String, DummyItem> ITEM_MAP = new HashMap<String, DummyItem>();
> 
> 
> 
> 
>     static {
>         // Add some sample items.
>        addItem(new DummyItem("1", "Klubnika Mürepbesi", "Klubnika Mürepbesi\n" +
>                "\n" +
>                "4-5 banka\n" +
>                "\n" +
>                "1 kg klubnika\n" +
>                "500 gr (2 bulgur) şeker\n" +
>                "\n" +
>                "1. Klubnikany süzgüçde goýup, sowuk suwda ýuwmaly. Soň klubnikanyň kök-ýapragyny aýyrmaly.\n" +
>                "\n" +
>                "2. Klubnikany çuňňur saja atyp, üstüne şeker guýup, 3 sagat goýmaly.\n" +
>                "\n" +
>                "3. Sajy aram otda goýmaly we şekeri ereýänçä bulamaly.\n" +
>                "\n" +
>                "4. Klubnikany ýuwaşlyk bilen 5 minut gaýnatmaly we sajy otdan aýryp, 6-8 sagat goýmaly (klubnika dargamaz ýaly).\n" +
>                "\n" +
>                "5. Sajy gaýtadan otda goýmaly we mürepbe goýalýança (10 minut) gaýnatmaly.\n" +
>                "\n" +
>                "6. Gazana suw guýup, otda goýmaly. Onuň üstünde demir gözenegi goýmaly. Mürepbe guýuljak bankalary we olaryň gapaklaryny
> ýuwup, gaýnaýan suwuň bugunda 15 minut goýmaly.\n" +
>                "\n" +
>                "7. Mürepbe taýýar bolanda bankalary tutaç bilen seresaply tutup, bugdan aýyrmaly. Bankalaryň içine gaýnaýan mürepbeden
> guýup, olaryň gapagyny ýapyp, gatyja towlamaly.",R.drawable.mylogo));
>         addItem(new DummyItem("2", "Semeni", "Adatça semeni ýazda, Nowruz baýramyna gabat, bir näçe maşgala bolup, bilelikde bişirilýär.
> Nowruz baýramyňyz gutly bolsun!\n" +
>                 "\n" +
>                 "Semeni\n" +
>                 "\n" +
>                 "300 gr bugdaý\n" +
>                 "Suw\n" +
>                 "1 kg un\n" +
>                 "\n" +
>                 "1. Bugdaýy ýuwup, üstüne sowuk suw guýup goýmaly. Ertesi bugdaýyň suwuny döküp, täze suw guýmaly.\n" +
>                 "\n" +
>                 "2. Üçülenji gün bugdaýyň suwuny döküp, ýene birki gezek ýuwmaly. Soň ony ýalpak gaba guýup, endigan ýaýratmaly-da,
> üstüni çygly mata bilen örtüp, ýyly ýerde goýmaly. Bugdaý däneleri
> gowy şineleýänçä onuň üstündäki matany günde iki gezek öllemeli.
> Dört-bäşilenji gün bugdaýyň aşagynda ak we inçejik şineler has
> köpelýär, üstündäki baldajyklar çala ýaşyl öwsüp başlaýar. Altylanjy
> gün şinelän bugdaý semeni etmäge taýýar bolýar.\n" +
>                 "\n" +
>                 "3. Bugdaýyň baldaklaryny, köklerini bölüşdirip, blendere (elektrik garyja) atyp, onuň üstüne azajyk suw* guýmaly we
> üwemeli (ýa-da et üwelýände üwäp, soň suw garmaly).\n" +
>                 "\n" +
>                 "4. Süzgüjiň içine iki gat hasa ýazmaly. Süzgüji çuňňur gabyň üstünde goýup, bugdaý üwelende emele gelen süýtli
> suwuklygy süzgüçden geçirmeli. Hasanyň gyralaryny epläp, bugdaý lötüni
> sykmaly. Hasanyň içindäki löti blendere atyp, gaýtadan suw guýup, ýene
> üwemeli we süzgüçden geçirmeli. Muny 3 gezek gaýtalamaly (2-nji hem
> 3-nji gezekde suwuklygyň reňki açygrak bolýar).\n" +
>                 "\n" +
>                 "5. Uly gazana un guýup, onuň üstüne az-azdan süýtli suwuklygy guýup, düwür galmaz ýaly, gowy garmaly. Soňra gazany aram
> otda goýmaly we unly garyndy gowy goýalýança dowamly bulamaly.
> Garyndynyň reňki 25-30 minutdan goňralyp başlaýar. Garyndy suwuny doly
> çekende, onuň üstüne 2 bulgur suw guýmaly we ýene 5 minut bulamaly.
> Gazanyň oduny öçürip, gapagyny ýapyp, 25-30 minut goýmaly. Taýýar
> bolan semenini gaba guýup, sowaýança goýmaly.", R.drawable.mylogo));
>         addItem(new DummyItem("3", "Kokosly Köke", "Kokosly Köke\n" +
>                 "\n" +
>                 "50 gr mesge\n" +
>                 "2 ýumurtga\n" +
>                 "150 gr şeker\n" +
>                 "200 gr gury, süýjüsiz kokos\n" +
>                 "\n" +
>                 "Mesgäni pes otda eretmeli. Eredilen mesge sowaýança başga bir gapda ýumurtga bilen şekeri garmaly. Emele gelen garyndynyň
> üstüne eredilen mesgäni guýmaly we bulamaly. Soňra onuň üstüne kokos
> guýup, gowy garmaly.\n" +
>                 "\n" +
>                 "Ojagy öňünden 180°C (356°F) derejede gyzdyrmaly. Ojak tabasynyň içine ojak kagyzyny ýazmaly. Taýýar bolan garyndydan bir çaý
> çemçesi möçberinde alyp, iki eliň aýasynda togalap, topjagaz ýasamaly.
> Topjagazlary, arasynda 2 sm töweregi boşluk goýup, kagyz ýazylan taba
> düzmeli. Kökäni ojagyň ortaky gatynda goýup, ýüzi çalaja gyzarýança
> (15-18 minut) bişirmeli.", R.drawable.mylogo));
>         addItem(new DummyItem("4", "Süýtli Tüwi", "Süýtli Tüwi \n" +
>                 "\n" +
>                 "4 adamlyk\n" +
>                 "\n" +
>                 "1 l süýt\n" +
>                 "200 gr (1 bulgur) tüwi\n" +
>                 "2 çaý çemçesi şeker\n" +
>                 "1 bölejik mesge\n" +
>                 "\n" +
>                 "Gazana süýt guýup, güýçli otda goýmaly. Süýt gaýnansoň tüwi atyp bulamaly we aram otda 10 minut bişirmeli. Soňra
> tüwä bir bölejik mesge atmaly we ony ýene 5 minut (ýumşaýança)
> bişirmeli. Soň tüwä şeker atyp garmaly we gazanyň oduny öçürmeli.",
> R.drawable.mylogo));
>         addItem(new DummyItem("5", "Medowik", "Medowik\n" +
>                 "\n" +
>                 "Kökesi üçin\n" +
>                 "6 ýumurtga\n" +
>                 "2 nahar çemçesi bal\n" +
>                 "200 gr şeker\n" +
>                 "200 gr mesge\n" +
>                 "800 gr un\n" +
>                 "1 çaý çemçesi hamyr tozy\n" +
>                 "\n" +
>                 "Kremi üçin\n" +
>                 "1 l süýt\n" +
>                 "300 gr şeker\n" +
>                 "300 gr mesge, otag ýylylygynda\n" +
>                 "4 nahar çemçesi un\n" +
>                 "\n" +
>                 "Tortuň kökesini taýýarlamak üçin ilki saçda mesge eretmeli. Eredilen mesge sowaýança başga bir gapda ýumurtgany, baly,
> şekeri garmaly. Emele gelen garyndynyň üstüne eredilen mesgäni guýup
> bulamaly.\n" +
>                 "\n" +
>                 "Pitä suw guýup, otda goýmaly we suw gaýnanda, garyndyly gaby pitiniň üstünde goýup, gaýnaýan suwuň bugunda 10 minut
> bulap durmaly. Garyndyny bugdan aýyrmaly, una hamyr tozuny garmaly we
> garyndynyň üstüne az-azdan un guýup bulamaly, ýumşajyk hamyr etmeli.
> Hamyry 10 bölege bölmeli we 30 minut sowadyjyda goýmaly.\n" +
>                 "\n" +
>                 "Ojagy öňünden 250 derejede gyzdyrmaly. Hamyryň her bölegini 30 sm tegeleklikde ýaýmaly we olary ýeke-ýekeden ýüzi
> gyzarynça bişirmeli. Bişen kökeleriň her birini ojakdan çykaran
> dessiňe, gatamaka 28 cm tegeleklikde kesmeli.\n" +
>                 "\n" +
>                 "Tortuň kremini taýýarlamak üçin bir pitä süýt we şeker guýup, pes otda gaýnatmaly we ony tagta çemçe bilen bulap
> durmaly. Süýt 20 minut gaýnansoň, onuň içine az-azdan un guýmaly we
> dowamly bulamaly. Süýt goýalanda, onuň oduny öçürmeli we sowaýança
> goýmaly. Mesgäni mikser bilen bulamaly we süýtli garyndyny mesgäniň
> üstüne az-azdan guýup, ýene mikser bilen bulamaly.\n" +
>                 "\n" +
>                 "Taýýar bolan tort kökelerini bitewi tort etmek üçin ilki bir kökäniň ýüzüne krem çalmaly. Soňra ikinji kökäniň arkasyna
> süýt çalyp, ony birinji kökäniň üstünde goýmaly we ýüzüne krem
> çalmaly. Şu tertipde tort kökelerini üsti-üstüne örüp,
> birleşdirmeli.\n" +
>                 "\n" +
>                 "Köke kesilende gyrasyndan galan bölekleri oklawy bilen owradyp, owuntyk etmeli we ony tortuň üstüne we gapdallaryna
> sepelemeli. Kremiň kokelere gowy siňmegi üçin torty bir gije
> goýmaly.", R.drawable.mylogo));
> 
>     }
> 
>     private static void addItem(DummyItem item) {
>         ITEMS.add(item);
>         ITEM_MAP.put(item.id, item);
>     }
> 
>     private static DummyItem createDummyItem(int position) {
>         int imageResources = 5;
>         return new DummyItem(String.valueOf(position), "Item " + position, makeDetails(position), imageResources);
>     }
> 
>     private static String makeDetails(int position) {
>         StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
>         builder.append("Details about Item: ").append(position);
>         for (int i = 0; i < position; i++) {
>             builder.append("\nMore details information here.");
>         }
>         return builder.toString();
>     }
> 
>     /**
>      * A dummy item representing a piece of content.
>      */
>     public static class DummyItem {
>         public final String id;
>         public final String content;
>         public final String details;
>         public final int imageResources;
> 
>         public DummyItem(String id, String content, String details, int imageResources) {
>             this.id = id;
>             this.content = content;
>             this.details = details;
>             this.imageResources = imageResources;
>         }
> 
>         @Override
>         public String toString() {
>             return content;
>         }
>     } }
```

Any help on this highly appreciated.

Comment: Please form an actual question in the post body

Comment: how can I add image to my project by java command